# Always save specific file type in windows to one location?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, registry

I'm trying to do the following I'm not sure if it's possible using VB.NET.
I want to specify default saving point for all files type for example:

In my program you choose the path "C:\Users\Markus\Pictures" for pictures and everytime you download pictures files from website, or using skype or any other program when Save File Dialog opens up (external one not via my program or connected to vb.net just the windows default one) then it will show "C:\Users\Markus\Pictures" always for .jpg .gif type of files etc...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bits of codes should solve your problem

```
SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Markus\Pictures"
```

InitialDirectory property represents the directory to be displayed when the open file dialog appears first time.

```
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*"
```

Filter property represents the filter on an open file dialog that is used to filter the type of files to be loaded during the browse option in an open file dialog.

[refer to this link for more info](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/mahesh/savefiledialog-in-VB-Net/)

Comment: But this will only work for the application itself right? I want it to be default for the windows for the user so if user goes to a website via Google Chrome and saves a picture some where over the computer it will show right away "C:\Users\Markus\Pictures" as default and not last saved or anything like that, I think it's got to do with the registry?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically modify the paths of the Windows special directories (My Pictures, etc) in the registry key:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders**

However, your app will have to be granted permissions to do so (see [RegistryPermission Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.registrypermission%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Y1300))

Of course, this will work for those file types that have entries in this registry key, and only if an external application uses this key